# How to create your own CRS using sf package in R

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, spatial-statistics, sf, tmap

I am trying to map basketball shots using the `sf` package in R to create interactive maps for players and coaches. I have managed to create a basketball court as a spatial object using [Todd Schneider's](https://github.com/toddwschneider/ballr) `ballr` , `plot_court()` function (more specifically the `court_points`).

```
library(sf)
spatial_court_points <- st_as_sf(court_points, coords = c("x", "y"))

court = st_sf(
  aggregate(
    spatial_court_points$geometry,
    list(spatial_court_points$desc),
    function(g){
      st_cast(st_combine(g),"MULTILINESTRING")
    }
  ))

plot(court)
```

[image: court]

I have also divided the court into 17 zones as seen in the picture below:

[image: 17 zones]

Let's say I have 5 shots with the following coordinates:

```
shots <- data.frame(
  x = c(8, -12, 0, 23, -16),
  y = c(8, 16, 30, 6, 12),
  made = as.factor(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
)

plot_court(court_theme = court_themes$light) +
  geom_point(data = shots, aes(x,y, shape = made))
```

[image: shots]

How should I go about mapping these shots using the `sf` package? When I use `tmap`, I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
Currect projection of shape polys unknown. Long-lat (WGS84) is assumed.
```

[image: tmap]

And the court happens to be plotted over the world map where I want the entire window to be the basketball court. How to I set the crs for my objects so that it is a rectangular grid from (-25, 0) to (25, 35)?

[image: crs]